# Исключить пользователей из выдачи при select запросе

Tags: php, sql

Есть массив из id пользователей: Array ( [0] => 288988637 [1] => 102818561 [2] => 302582329 [3] => 338311920 )

Есть так же селект запрос на рандомный вывод пользователей.

```
$Query2 = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `vip` = 1 AND (тут нужно взять массив, который показал выше, и вывести других юзеров, чтоб не попались те, которые есть в массиве) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
```

То есть нужно в запросе исключить пользователей из массива. Вывести других четырёх людей, главное что-бы имеющиеся в массиве не вывелись.

Comment: `... AND id NOT IN (id1, id2, id3...)`, где-то были похожие вопросы, там было расписано как можно динамически эти id подставлять

Comment: ... AND `uid` NOT IN (" . implode(',', $array) . ") может так?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(288988637,102818561,302582329,338311920);
$query = "SELECT `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `vip` = 1 AND id NOT IN( '" . implode($array, "', '") . "' ) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4";
$Query2 = mysqli_query($CONNECT, $query);
```